# when i do destructuring to initialize multiple variables via use state hook code works but it doesnt work when i do object destructuring

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, react-hooks, object-destructuring

here is my part of code for signup form

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import useForm from "../useForm";
import validate from "../validation";
import {
  isValidLength,
  isContainsLowercase,

} from "../passwordValidation";   
const SignupForm = () => {

My question is when I use  useState to initialize values the code doesnt work but when i do destructuring individually for multiple variables the code works. why is that?
```

// here i am doing object destructuring

```
  // const [validationRules, setValidationRules] = useState({
  //   validLength: false,
  //   containsLowercase: false,
 });
```

// here i am intializing variables individually using destructuring

```
  const [validLength, setValidLength] = useState(false);
  const [containsLowercase, setContainsLowercase] = useState(false);


  function handlePassword(e) {
    let new_Password = e.target.value;
   
    if (isValidLength.test(new_Password)) {
      // setValidationRules({
      //   ...validationRules,
      //   validLength: true,
      // });
            // OR

      setValidLength(true);
```

---

```
but the thing is the code gives error when i write this

 const [validationRules, setValidationRules] = useState({
    validLength: false,
    containsLowercase: false,
    containsUppercase: false,
    containsNumber: false,
    containsSymbol: false,
  });
 function handlePassword(e) {
    let new_Password = e.target.value;
    console.log(new_Password);
    if (isValidLength.test(new_Password)) {
      setValidationRules({
        ...validationRules,
        validLength: true,
      });
     
    } else {

      setValidationRules({
        ...validationRules,
        validLength: false,
      });
    }

    if (isContainsLowercase.test(new_Password)) {
      setValidationRules({
        ...validationRules,
        containsLowercase: true,
      });
    } else {
      setValidationRules({
        ...validationRules,
        containsLowercase: false,
      });
    }

    if (isContainsUppercase.test(new_Password)) {
      setValidationRules({
        ...validationRules,
        containsUppercase: true,
      });
    } else {
      setValidationRules({
        ...validationRules,
        containsUppercase: false,
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the error is caused because you are modifying the state instead of overwrite. Try this:

```js
setValidLength(prevState => {...prevState, validLength: true})
```

This way you take the previous state value and overwrite the `validLenght` atribute.